# R package for geographic regions

Tags: r

Someone told me about a R package with the definition of objects some regions and nations boundaries. I'm trying to find the border of Veneto, an italian region. What's the name of the package? Do you know an alternative way to find that border (I'm not sure that Veneto is included in the package)??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Howabout:

```
require(raster)
veneto =  subset(getData('GADM', country='ITA', level=1), NAME_1=="Veneto")
plot(veneto)
```

[image: Veneto]

Comment: do you know a good reference about SpatialPolygonsDataFrame? I have to do a big work on this, and I want to know all about this objects..

Comment: https://github.com/Robinlovelace/Creating-maps-in-R/ is a good starter tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You can also work with TopoJSON/GeoJSON files that are popular with the D3 crowd:

```
library(rgdal)
library(RCurl)
library(ggplot2)
library(rgeos)

# for theme_map()
devtools::source_gist("https://gist.github.com/hrbrmstr/33baa3a79c5cfef0f6df")

# location of Italy TopoJSON file
url <- "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/andreaangeli/5b64a102e357198780e9/raw/e076b45eb2fcb8de6a0ec612f863499181bb494b/ita.json"

download.file(url, destfile="ita.json", method="curl")

ogrListLayers("ita.json") # to see that the layer is "reg2011"

ita <- readOGR("ita.json", "reg2011")

veneto <- ita[ita$id == 5,] # region 5 is Veneto

# could just plot(veneto) now, but I like ggplot better

veneto_map <- fortify(veneto, region="id")

gg <- ggplot(data=veneto_map) 
gg <- gg + geom_map(map=veneto_map, aes(map_id=id, group=group, x=long, y=lat), color="black", fill="white")
gg <- gg + coord_map()
gg <- gg + theme_map()
gg
```

[image]

You can also work with "normal" shapefiles and this one is (most likely) what's in the `raster` package referenced in Spacedman's post:

```
download.file("http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/diva/adm/ITA_adm.zip", "ITA_adm.zip")
unzip("ITA_adm.zip", exdir="ITA_adm")

ita <- readOGR("ITA_adm/", "ITA_adm1")

veneto <- ita[ita$NAME_1 == "Veneto",] # this shapefile has region names in it!

veneto_map <- fortify(veneto)

gg <- ggplot(data=veneto_map) 
gg <- gg + geom_map(map=veneto_map, aes(map_id=id, group=group, x=long, y=lat), color="black", fill="white")
gg <- gg + coord_map()
gg <- gg + theme_map()
gg
```

[image]

Comment: thank you! but how about venezia? it has been sliced off from that map..

Comment: It's been "optimized/simplified. Many TopoJSON/GeoJSON files try to reduce the number of polygons so shapes draw faster (the more polygons, the slower it will be). Regional-level shapefiles will often do this polygon optimization as well (i.e. it's not a feature limited to TopoJSON/GeoJSON). Even the administrative-level shapefiles from here: http://www.istat.it/it/archivio/24613 have been simplified. If you need the detail, it's possible to find other sources (like the built-in one Spacedman showed). For _many_ mapping needs, the boundary details are not important.

Comment: I literally found that one after a 2s google search, too. There are plenty more out there.

Comment: Its also been squashed because it treats lat-long like equal partners. Sort out projections before you tell people how to make squashed maps.

Comment: My bad. Meant to do `coord_map()` and ended up doing `geom_map()` twice. Glad it wad delivered snarkily.